# How to remove objects in an array by its value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and this is my response of my routes.

[image]

I want to **REMOVE** the objects that have the value of `"existence":false`  and output the object that has value of "existence":true"

This is my code so far.

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:confUid/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
    getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
      results.contacts=contacts;
      res.send('response('+JSON.stringify(results.contacts)+')');
    }); 
  } else{
      res.send('response('+JSON.stringify(results.contacts)+')');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var filtered = results.contacts.filter(function(c) {
  return c.existence;
});

res.send('response(' +JSON.stringify(filtered) + ')');
```

Comment: Hello @Buzinas . I want to remove the object that has the value of `"existence":false"` and output the object that has value of `"existence":true"`

Comment: @Agent69 that's exactly what I'm doing here ;)

Comment: If you don't like the readability, you can change the `filter` return to `return c.existence === true;`. But since it's already a boolean, there is absolutely no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var filtered = results.contacts.filter(function(contact) {
    return contact.existence;
});
```